# How can we write java code in JMETER?

Tags: jmeter

How can we write java code in JMETER?

I got some information from google,Java Sampler is using for that and I tried that way
Just i did copy paste some codes from googe,but getting errors from import also ,Always org.apache.jmeter is showing error,Any body can tell me about implementation and sample code alao

This is my java code

```
package com.code4reference.jmeter.functions;
import org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable; 
import org.apache.jmeter.functions.AbstractFunction; 

public class JavaRequestSamplerDemo extends AbstractJavaSamplerClient {

  @Override
  public SampleResult runTest(JavaSamplerContext ctx) {
    JMeterVariables vars = JMeterContextService.getContext().getVariables();
    vars.put("demo", "demoVariableContent");

    SampleResult sampleResult = new SampleResult();
    sampleResult.setSuccessful(true);
    sampleResult.setResponseCodeOK();
    sampleResult.setResponseMessageOK();
    return sampleResult;
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're missing org.apache.jmeter.* package you need to add everything all jars from /lib/ext folder of your JMeter installation to Java build classpath. Refer to your IDE documentation on how to do it.

In Eclipse it can be done via Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path
In Idea it's in Project -> Dependencies
If you're using Apache Ant, you need to do something like

```
<path id="build.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${path.to.your.jmeter.lib.ext.folder">
        <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
<path>
```

There are at least 3 places where you can inject your Java code.

**1. Java Request**.

Examples:

- /src/protocol/java/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/java/test/JavaTest.java
- /src/protocol/java/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/java/test/SleepTest.java

Which are source code for JavaTest and SleepTest Java Request Samplers

**2. Your own Sampler**

Example:

- /src/examples/org/apache/jmeter/examples/sampler/ExampleSampler.java

**3. Beanshell or JSR233 Sampler**

JMeter supports [Beanshell](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-using-functions) and JSR233 scripting, both can understand Java syntax.

JMeter source code is available from [JMeter Downloads page](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi).

Answer (score 1):

Except Java Sampler which requires
knowledge with specific JMeter context, other options:

1. You can write Java code in [JSR223 element](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) which is capable to execute any JSR223 supported language as groovy.

> The JSR223 Sampler allows JSR223 script code

2. Inside other JMeter elements, as If Controller, You can execute Java code inside [__BeanShell](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__BeanShell) function or [__groovy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy)

> For performance it is better to use __groovy function

3. Package your code in a jar and put it in JMeter's lib folder. Then you can execute its public methods.

Answer (score 0):

I would say use BeanShell for something like this unless what you are going for is to wrap some of the JMeter functionality into a Java app. It seems common for people to create test plans adding some more advanced functionality using BSF or BeanShell then running it all headlesss with Ant.